# $\int_{-1}^{+1} \sqrt{1-x^2 + g (1-x^4)} \: dx, \quad g > 0,$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to compute the following integral analytically

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{+1} \sqrt{1-x^2 + g (1-x^4)} \: dx, \quad g > 0,
\end{equation}

Here $g$ is a real parameter. I have tried to compute it in Mathematica but it fails to give a result. So I am wondering if the integral can be computed analytically. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that inequality can be simplified to $g\ge -\frac12$ for $x\in[-1,1]$

Comment: Dividing the integrand by $\sqrt {1 + g}$ gives $\int y dx$ with $y^2 = P(x) = (1 - x^2) (1 - m x^2)$. Then
$$\int \frac {P(x)} y dx =
\int y dx =
x y - \int \frac {x P'(x)} {2 y} dx.$$
That gives $\int x^4/y \, dx$ in terms of $\int x^2/y \, dx$ and $\int dx/y$ and therefore in terms of the elliptic integrals $F = \int dx/y$ and $E = \int (1 - m x^2)/y \, dx$. Thus
$$\int y dx =
\frac {1 + m} {3 m} E - \frac {1 - m} {3 m} F + \frac {x y} 3.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also find that Mathematica does not evaluate the integral, even when informed of the condition on the radicand.

```
Assuming[{g >= -1/(x^2 + 1)},
    Integrate[Sqrt[1 - x^2 + g (1 - x^4)], {x, -1, 1}]
]
```

$$  \int_{-1}^1 \; \sqrt{1-x^2 + g \cdot (1-x^4)} \,\mathrm{d}x  $$

However, the fundamental theorem of calculus allows us to use any antiderivative to compute the definite integral.  Since we've established Mathematica as a suitable method of integration,

```
Assuming[{g >= -1/(x^2 + 1)},
    Integrate[Sqrt[1 - x^2 + g (1 - x^4)], x]
]
```

$$  \frac{\sqrt{-g x^4+g-x^2+1} \left(g x \left(x^2-1\right) \left(g
   x^2+g+1\right)+\sqrt{-(g+1) \left(x^2-1\right) \left(g x^2+g+1\right)}
   \left(E\left(\sin ^{-1}(x)|\frac{1}{g+1}-1\right)-(2 g+1) F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}(x)|\frac{1}{g+1}-1\right)\right)\right)}{3 g \left(x^2-1\right) \left(g
   x^2+g+1\right)}  \text{,}  $$
where $E(\varphi|k^2)$ is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) and $F(\varphi|k^2)$ is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).  If we try to directly evaluate this at $-1$ or $1$, the result is undefined, so as usual for an improper integral, we take limits.

```
Simplify[(Limit[#, x -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow"] 
    - Limit[#, x -> -1, Direction -> "FromAbove"])] & [(
    Sqrt[1 + g - x^2 - x^4] (
        g x (-1 + x^2) (1 + g + g x^2) + 
        Sqrt[-(1 + g) (-1 + x^2) (1 + g + g x^2)] (EllipticE[
      ArcSin[x], -1 + 1/(1 + g)] - (1 + 2 g) EllipticF[
       ArcSin[x], -1 + 1/(1 + g)]))
    )/(3 g (-1 + x^2) (1 + g + g x^2))
]
```

$$  \frac{2 \sqrt{2 g^2+3 g+1} \left((2 g+1)
   K\left(-\frac{g}{g+1}\right)-E\left(-\frac{g}{g+1}\right)\right)}{3 g \sqrt{2
   g+1}}  \text{,}  $$
where $K(k)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) and $E(k)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

This is real-valued if $g \geq -1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$1-x^2+g(1-x^4)=-gx^4-x^2+(g+1)=-g\left[x^4+\frac{x^2}g-\frac{(g+1)}g\right]$$
$$x^4+\frac{x^2}{g}-\left(1+\frac1g\right)=\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2g}\right)^2-\left(1+\frac1g+\frac{1}{4g^2}\right)$$
now if for ease we say: $$\alpha=-g,\beta=\frac{1}{2g},\gamma=1+\frac1g+\frac1{4g^2}$$
now we have the integral in the form:
$$I=\sqrt{\alpha}\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{(x^2+\beta)^2-\gamma}\,dx$$
and now maybe try a trig substitution here

Answer (score 1):

The integral is even in $x$.  So in *Mathematica*:

$$2 \int\limits_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2 + g (1 - x^4)}\ dx = \frac{2 \sqrt{g+1} \left((2 g+1)
   K\left(\frac{1}{g+1}-1\right)-E\left(\frac{1}{g+1}-1\right)\right)}{3 g}$$