# $\int\cos(2 x) \sqrt{\sin^2(x) + 1}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

> How do we solve this integration?
> $$\int\cos(2 x) \sqrt{\sin^2(x) + 1}\, dx.$$

I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Ccos%282+x%29+%5Csqrt%7B%5Csin%5E2%28x%29+%2B+1%7D%5C%2C+dx),
the result is
$$\frac{1}{6}\left(8 \,F(x\mid-1) - 6\, E(x\mid-1) + \sin(2 x) \sqrt{6 - 2 \cos(2x)}\,\right) + C.$$

But I don't know how to get that within the steps.

I hope to get some help from you, please.

Comment: These can be expressed as Elliptic Integrals.

Comment: You cannot avoid elliptic integrals.. Are you sure that your  problem is not a definite integral ?

Comment: Let $u = \sin x$, then the integral becomes $\int (2 y - (1 - m u^2)/y) du$ with $y^2 = (1 - u^2) (1 - m u^2)$. To find $\int y du$, see the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3897125).

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a case where the process is smoother when you already know the goal.  First a few preliminaries with regards to WolframAlpha syntax:

The [Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) is given by $$F(x\mid m) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^{2}(\theta)}}$$
and the [Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) is given by
$$E(x\mid m) = \int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1 - m\sin^{2}(\theta)}\,d\theta.$$

We will also make use of several [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), in particular \begin{align*}
\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^{2}(x)\\
\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x).
\end{align*}

It is also worth noting that with the double-angle identity for $\cos$ we have that $$\sqrt{6 - 2 \cos(2x)} = \sqrt{6 - 2 + 4\sin^2(x)} = \sqrt{4 + 4\sin^{2}(x)} = 2\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}.$$

So, we will show that $$\int\cos(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}\, dx = \frac{1}{6}\left(8 \,F(x\mid-1) - 6\, E(x\mid-1) + 2\sin(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}\,\right) + C.$$

To this end, we have
\begin{align*}
\cos(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} &= (1 - 2\sin^{2}(x))\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}\\[5pt]
&=\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} - 2\sin^{2}(x)\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}\\[5pt]
&=\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} - \frac{2\sin^{2}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{2\sin^{4}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\\[5pt]
&=\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} - 2\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{2\sin^{4}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\\[5pt]
&=-\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{2\sin^{4}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}.
\end{align*}
Note that here we used
$$-\frac{2\sin^{2}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} = -\frac{2(1+\sin^{2}(x) - 1)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} = -\frac{2(1+\sin^{2}(x))}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}.$$

Continuing, then, we have
\begin{align*}
\cos(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} &=-\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{2\sin^{4}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\\[5pt]
&=-\frac{d}{dx}E(x\mid -1)+ 2\frac{d}{dx}F(x\mid -1)- \frac{2\sin^{4}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}.
\end{align*}
So, we will focus on the last term above, doing some adding/subtracting/manipulating until we get something we recognize:
\begin{align*}
\frac{2\sin^{4}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} &= \frac{2}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\left[3\sin^{4}(x)\right]\\[5pt]
&=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\biggl[1 - 1 + 2\sin^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)+2\sin^{4}(x) - \sin^{2}(x) + \sin^{4}(x)\biggr]\\[5pt]
&=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\biggl[1 - \bigl(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x)\bigr) - \bigl(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x)\bigr)\sin^{2}(x) - \bigl(1 - \sin^{2}(x)\bigr)\sin^{2}(x)\biggr]\\[5pt]
&=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\biggl[1 - \cos(2x) - \cos(2x)\sin^{2}(x) - \cos^{2}(x)\sin^{2}(x)\biggr]\\[5pt]
&=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\biggl[2 - 2\cos(2x)\bigl(1+ \sin^{2}(x)\bigr) - \sin(2x)\sin(x)\cos(x)\biggr]\\[5pt]
&=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{2\cos(2x)\bigl(1+ \sin^{2}(x)\bigr)}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{\sin(2x)\sin(x)\cos(x)}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}} - \frac{2}{3}\cos(2x)\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} -\frac{\sin(2x)\sin(x)\cos(x)}{3\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{2}{3}\frac{d}{dx}F(x\mid -1)-\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}.
\end{align*}

All together, then, we have
$$
\cos(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} = -\frac{d}{dx}E(x\mid -1)+ \frac{4}{3}\frac{d}{dx}F(x\mid -1)+\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)},
$$

which upon integrating gives us our desired result:
$$\int\cos(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} \,dx= -E(x\mid -1) + \frac{4}{3}F(x\mid -1) + \frac{1}{3}\sin(2x)\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)} + C$$

or upon factoring a $1/6$:
$$\int\cos(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}\, dx = \frac{1}{6}\left(8 \,F(x\mid-1) - 6\, E(x\mid-1) + 2\sin(2 x) \sqrt{1+\sin^{2}(x)}\,\right) + C.$$

Answer (score 1):

My preferred means of solving elliptic integrals is Byrd & Friedman's *Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Physicists*, and the derivation below will quote from it.

Rewrite the integrand as
$$\frac{1-\sin^2x-2\sin^4x}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}}$$
and then use formulas 282.00 and 282.04 to rewrite the integral (from $0$ to $x$) as$\newcommand{sd}{\operatorname{sd}}$
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}F(\psi,m)-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int_0^{F(\psi,m)}\sd^2u\,du-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int_0^{F(\psi,m)}\sd^4u\,du$$
where $m=\frac12$ and $\sin\psi=\frac{\sqrt2\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}}$. Now use 318.02 and 318.04 to solve the integrals of $\sd$, yielding the final result (after much simplification) as
$$\sqrt2(2F(\psi,m)/3-E(\psi,m))+\frac{2\sin2x-(\sin4x)/6}{\sqrt{6-2\cos2x}}$$